# why i need to use spread operator and make clone object to update object properties in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

i just want to know why i need to use spread operator to update object properties in react & redux for example i have this function that take list of items and item that i want to modify it
if i type it by this syntax it work

```
export const decreaseCartItem = (item , itemToInc) => {

    return item.map(item => itemToInc.id === item.id ? {...item , qty : item.qty - 1} : item);
  

}
```

why i can't to modify it directly like this ??

```
export const decreaseCartItem = (item , itemToInc) => {

    return item.map(item => itemToInc.id === item.id ? item.qty - 1 : item);
  

}
```

why the first syntax it work but the sec in not work when i use it in redux reducer and in react and why i need to make clone object and return it ?

i hope to find answer

Comment: First of all, the second code sets the item to a number, so it won't work even if you were allowed to mutate state. However React relies on using a completely new object, because if you just modify an object's property, React cannot detect the change.

Comment: Those are totally different. If `itemToInc.id === item.id ?` in your first example is true then an Object will be assigned as one of the Array properties of the Array that the `.map` returns. If the same ternary in the second example is true, then a Number will be assigned as one of the Array properties of the Array that the `.map` returns. The spread operator is merging that argument passed Object in your first example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in the second one you are mapping the item to it's quantity - 1, instead of the item to an identical object, except it's quantity reduced by one.

```js
const itemToInc = {id: 1}
console.log([{id: 1, qty: 2}].map(item => itemToInc.id === item.id ? item.qty - 1 : item));
console.log([{id: 1, qty: 2}].map(item => itemToInc.id === item.id ? {...item, qty: item.qty - 1} : item));
```